# How can I git add, commit and push in one line with multiple specified file?

Tags: github

I want to combine the git push command to one line, such as `gitpush -m "fix bug #123" -f file1.html, file2.html ...`

only file1.html and file2.html will commit and update to the server

how to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding the following function to your .bashrc (or .bash_profile if Mac):

```
function allinone() {

    for i in ${@:2}
    do
        git add $i
    done

    git commit -a -m "$1"
    git push

}
```

Then you just can add, commit and push typing:

```
allinone "Adding, commiting and pushing 3 files at once" file1.html file2.html file3.html
```

The first parameter must be the comment, and the rest of the parameters are the files that you want to add, commit and push (notice that files are separated by spaces)

I hope this helps!